# Has anyone implemented Google Pagespeed Module into Magento?

Tags: google-api

Has anyone installed Google Pagespeed Module into Magento? Is the implementation too hard to do it?

Comment: Why don't you use the actual server side Google Pagespeed extension? This isn't something Magento should be doing. Here's some starter configuration for you if using MageStack https://www.sonassihosting.com/help/magestack/optimal-varnishpagespeed-configuration/

Comment: I thought Google was killing it off?

Comment: No, they stopped the PageSpeed hosted product, not the open source module. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/page-speed-service-discuss/h4jyUpv6Bc8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the one good module which allows you to configure google pagespeed easily.

Play with it

https://github.com/mediarox/pagespeed

I strictly recommend you to use this one in your dev. environment. Once you test all the features, You can move into production.Cheers.

Comment: Tks so much for the tip. However, have you implemented it in a website? Is  it too hard to do it? Does it work well with magento?

Comment: No, Its not that hard. It is very easy. Tanmay Kamath point is good. 
Accept mine as answer if it satisfy your quench LOL. :)

Comment: Tks so much! ;) I will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

The module was easy to implement and worked as expected. However with FPC on it stopped working, so we uninstalled it.

Answer (score 0):

Nope its not hard. Download the file from the link above. Place the files in appropriate folders. Edit the config file as per your needs. Login to magento admin panel. Configuration path: System > Configuration > ADVANCED > Pagespeed
You will be able to see the pagespeed module there.

Comment: Tks very much! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I just thought I would share an outline of my recent efforts using the pagespeed_mod on Apache.  It greatly improves page loading speed but is a pest when trying to update the site.  This is the approach I took to make it less of a pain:

1: In the pagespeed module conf I set the cache directory to be inside the Magento var folder to make it easier for web scripts and my remote access user to get to it.

2: Wrote a script to recursively delete the contents of that said folder. See [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338123/how-do-i-recursively-delete-a-directory-and-its-entire-contents-files-sub-dir) on this.

3: Added a new button to the clear cache admin page to call said script.  You can do this by adding admin layout xml similar to this:

```
     <adminhtml_cache_index>
        <reference name="cache.additional">
            <block type="core/template" name="jh-pagespeedcache" template="pagespeedcache.phtml"/>
        </reference>
     </adminhtml_cache_index>
```

You can base your phtml contents on the existing clear cache buttons.

Just saves a bit of time and annoyance when you need to update the live site.